# JavaScript manipulate string problem

Tags: javascript, string

var a

```
var a = "ACdA(a = %b, ccc= 2r2)";
```

var b

```
var b = "\ewfsd\ss.jpg"
```

Expected outputs:

```
var c = "ACdA(a = %b, ccc= 2r2, b_holder = \ewfsd\ss.jpg)"
```

It adds the string b to the end of string a, that's it! But be careful of the ")"

"b_holder " is hard coded string, it's absolutly same in all cases, won't be changed.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You are missing quote marks around your strings in declaration. Post your actual code. What is Method ACdA? Post code for that as well. Honestly, I don't know what I'm looking at...

Comment: Remarkable! You haven't provided a _single_ line of code, and **just** on the day that my crystal ball is in the shop... what a coincidence.

Comment: What is the question or problem here?

Comment: So, you made code that does this?  Does it work?

Comment: Can you show that you tried/thought of something before just asking for a solution? Have a look at string concatenation and substring methods in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Concatenate `", b_holder = "` to var `b`, and
2. Replace `")"` in var `a` with the result of the concatenation.

Since this is homework, I'll leave it to you to figure out which methods to use. Good luck!

Hint: you can either store the result of the concatenation in step (1) in another variable, or you can do it all in one line.

Edit: You also need to concatenate the `")"` back onto the end. So maybe three things. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You *still* don't show any code for what you're doing with `a` and `b` to produce `c`; you are just showing a simple assignment of the expected (desired) value.

You have a problem, however with the value you're assigning to `var b` -- because the backslash `\` is an *escape*.  If you want a backslash in the actual string you need to double it, so your assignment would be

```
var b = "\\ewfsd\\ss.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "ACdA(a = %b, ccc= 2r2)";
var b = "\\ewfsd\\ss.jpg"; // need to escape the backslash for RegExp replace
var re = /\)$/;
var c = a.replace(re, ", b_holder = "+b+"\)");
```